# Managing Azure PIM permissions

Tags: azure

I have a single tenant with a single subscription. I have a custom role configured:

- rbac role: for managing rbac on Azure Resources. Contains Microsoft.Authorization/*

Now I noticed that when I activate my rbac role I am unable to edit any roles or role assignments from the PIM panel.
However, when I activate the Owner role there are no issues.

I've been looking through the Operations, but I don't see anything other than Microsoft.Authorization provider that should be needed. Yet I am still missing something for my rbac role. Does anyone know in which provider I am supposed to look? I'm trying to downscope permissions.

Comment: For management from PIM, shouldn't you have the 'Privileged Role Administrator" permissions instead of the Microsoft.Authorization on the individual services?

Comment: Privileged Role Administrator is an Azure AD role. It has no relation to Azure Resources. Also, I had tested that to make sure I was not mistaken. :)